# uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin error when deploying on vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm trying to deploy my rails app on a VPS with capistrano and I am having this issue:
Everything works well in development.
Anyone knows how to approach this?

2013-11-18 21:41:44 executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing "cd /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/releases/20131119023851 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["66.228.34.47"]
    [66.228.34.47] executing command
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/releases/20131119023851/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in`'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in`each'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/releases/20131119023851/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`require_environment!'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
 ** [out :: 66.228.34.47] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 22955ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/henrik41/apps/woomatch/releases/20131119023851 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on 66.228.34.47

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?  Is active_admin inside a group (e.g. development) in your Gemfile?

Comment: Thanks Peter. You pinpointed the exact problem. My activeadmin was misplaced in my assets group. I displaced and now it migrates properly. You rock!

Comment: @PeterGoldstein thanks! can you add it as an answer please so that i can upvote

Answer (score 2):

If active_admin is located inside a group (e.g. 'development' or 'assets') and is not available in the production environment it can cause this error.